# Improving System 1 and System 2 collaboration?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience

I'm an inquisitive novice with 60+ life years experience. My current top interest is the improvement of solutions created by organizations of teams solving complex problems cooperatively .

Is there any active or prior research on the feasibility of self-improvement in effective collaborative coordination between System 1 and System 2 that most often results in positive outcomes? Or any Sys1-Sys2 improved cooperation.

Specifically, I'm looking for a physiological and psychological basis to evaluate experiments designed to improve team and organizational best practices in collaborative problem solving.